# Postgresql new replica stuck/very slow: sending write flush

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, timescaledb

I have tried to set up a replica on PostgreSQL 11. The slave database is not starting, and I can see log messages like:

DEBUG Sending write DD90/8D0E3258 flush DD90/8D0E3258 apply DD90/8D0E3258

Although the numbers are increasing, the replica is not reachable and still in the start up process. Can someone explain what might be going on and what I may have done wrong? I'm not sure how to proceed.

I actually stopped PostgreSQL, then cloned it and added the recovery.conf to the data directory. I was expecting that everything would run very fast again. One remark, the database is rather large, 1TB, and also uses Timescale as a plugin.

On the primary, the command `pg_replication_slots`:

```
Name               |Value         |
-------------------+--------------+
slot_name          |replica_1_slot|
plugin             |              |
slot_type          |physical      |
datoid             |              |
database           |              |
temporary          |false         |
active             |true          |
active_pid         |5989          |
xmin               |              |
catalog_xmin       |              |
restart_lsn        |DD90/8D0B90E0 |
confirmed_flush_lsn|              |
```

And `pg_stat_replication`

```
Name            |Value                        |
----------------+-----------------------------+
pid             |6046                         |
usesysid        |442052913                    |
usename         |repuser                      |
application_name|r1                           |
client_addr     |192.168.88.28                |
client_hostname |                             |
client_port     |38936                        |
backend_start   |2023-04-11 09:42:50.014 +0200|
backend_xmin    |                             |
state           |streaming                    |
sent_lsn        |DD90/8D0F76F8                |
write_lsn       |DD90/8D0F76F8                |
flush_lsn       |DD90/8D0F76F8                |
replay_lsn      |DD90/8D0F76F8                |
write_lag       |                             |
flush_lag       |                             |
replay_lag      |                             |
sync_priority   |0                            |
sync_state      |async                        |
```

PS: It seems that  hot-standby  was missing in the config. So the database did not respond.

Comment: What else is in the log file?  Do you even have it configured to start up in hot-standby mode, or is it just configured as a warm standby?  When you try to connect, what is the exact message you get?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. You are right maybe this was the issue, the replica seems to work. Although confirmed_flush_lsn is NULL that is kind of strange.